# Stop the Test Execution if the Smoke Test Fails

Tags: maven, testng, pom.xml

I have 2 testng.xml files called testng_smoke.xml and testng_regression.xml. I've configured the pom.xml as below to run these testng files.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng_smoke.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng_regression.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

In here it executes both testng files and give the status of the build (Success or Fail) at the end.

But my requirement is to run the smoke test suite (testng_smoke.xml) first and fail the build without moving to regression test suite (testng_regression.xml) if there any test failure in the smoke test suite. Is there any possibility to achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no out of the box way in testng to do this.

If you are using Jenkins or some CI, then it is better to create two jobs or pipeline so that the second task is dependent on the results of the first one.

If not and you want to use single file then one of the possible solutions may be to maintain a variable either as a file or an environment variable who's value can be set in the suiteListener afterSuite method.  The beforeSuite method can then throw a SkipException to ignore the suite based on the variable value.